# Finding text between tags and replacing it along with the tags

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am using The following regex pattern to find text between `[code]` and `[/code]` tags:

```
(?<=[code]).*?(?=[/code])
```

It returns me anything which is enclosed between these 2 tags, e.g. this: `[code]return Hi There;[/code]` gives me `return Hi There;`.

I need help with regex to replace entire text **along** with the tags.

Comment: For example, I would like to replace all the occurrences of ** [code] and text enclosed within [/code] ** with some other text. I just managed to get this working @"[code].*?[/code]... Can this be improved further?

Comment: What's the problem with this `\[code].*?\[/code]` pattern?

Comment: I am not so great with regex, so was wondering if I've missed anything? To be precise is [code].*?[/code] good enough to return me the entire code block along with the tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
var s = "My temp folder is: [code]Path.GetTempPath()[/code]";

var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\[code](.*?)\[/code]",
    m =>
        {
            var codeString = m.Groups[1].Value;

            // then evaluate this string
            return EvaluateMyCode(codeString)
        });
```

Comment: Just one more thing, I am okay with using [] however using <> gives me an exception System.ArgumentException: parsing "\<code>(.*?)\</code>" - Reference to undefined group name code...

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk why have you used a lambda expression here?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Sorry I wasn't suggesting that your answer was wrong or a poor answer. However doesn't the call to Regex.Replace replace all instances matching the regex in the string passed in? I must admit I’m not very strong on lambda expressions.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a HTML Parser for this. I can see that what you are trying to do is simple, however these things have a habit to get much more complicated overtime. The end result is much pain for the poor sole who has to maintain the code in the future.

Take a look at this question about HTML Parsers
[What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

**[Edit]**
Here is a much more relevant answer to the question asked.
@Milad Naseri regex is correct you just need to do something like

```
string matchCodeTag = @"\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]";
string textToReplace = "[code]The Ape Men are comming[/code]";
string replaceWith = "Keep Calm";
string output = Regex.Replace(textToReplace, matchCodeTag, replaceWith);
```

Check out this web sites for more examples
http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace
http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/csharp-regular-expressions.html

Hope this helps

Comment: I agree it would be preferable to have a parser instead of a regex since parentese matching is notoriously brittle in regex and substituting ( with [code] and ) with [/code] doesn't change that. However what OP has posted is not HTML so I can't see how an HTML parse would help here

Comment: @Rune FS Apologies I made an assumption here, in fact a rather large one. Have you considered using a tool like regex buddy http://www.regexbuddy.com/ it cost 30 euros but well worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use back referencing, i.e. replace `\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]` with something like `<code>$1</code>` which will give you what's been enclosed by the `[code][/code]` tags enclosed in -- for this example -- `<code></code>` tags.

Comment: Sorry I thing I missed a point. \[code].*?\[/code] replaces everything in the string which may have multiple tags like these. The tags contain c# code, which must be executed and replaced by the string it returns. So entire [Code] and what ever c# is inside [/code] must be replaced with the return value.