# Regex should take text between the two points and write something else

Tags: c#, regex

That's how I have to regex some text. Where, for example, I just wrote `#member#` then it just "**hello**"

which I want but oppose if I write `\#medlem\#.*\#memberstop\#` where to take everything between `#member#` and `#memberstop#` All the text that goes through it should just replace it with hello.

```
text = Regex.Replace("<p>hello world! #member# Hello World #memberstop# test data</p>", @"\#member\#.*\#memberstop\#", m => { return "Hello"; });
```

This where work good:

```
text = Regex.Replace("<p>hello world! #member# Hello World #memberstop# test data</p>", @"\#member\#", m => { return "Hello"; });
    enter code here
```

Here it comes out and exchanges # member # with hello.

I have look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870169/11141703

Comment: `medlemstop` is not the same as `memberstop`

Comment: Do you just want the text **between** `#member#` and `#memberstop#` replaced? Or the whole thing, including `#member#` and `#memberstop#`?

Comment: i mean:  including #member# and #memberstop#

Answer (score 0):

not sure, what´s the goal, but 2 possibilities to replace the text between the member-tags:
[http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c%23member%5c%23%29.*%28%5c%23memberstop%5c%23%29&i=%3cp%3ehello+world!+%23member%23+Hello+World+%23memberstop%23+test+data%3c%2fp%3e%22&r=%241hello%242](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%23member%5C%23%29.*%28%5C%23memberstop%5C%23%29&i=%3Cp%3Ehello%20world!%20%23member%23%20Hello%20World%20%23memberstop%23%20test%20data%3C%2Fp%3E%22&r=%241hello%242).

or with lookahead/behind:

[http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%23member%5c%23%29.*%28%3f%3d%5c%23memberstop%5c%23%29&i=%3cp%3ehello+world!+%23member%23+Hello+World+%23memberstop%23+test+data%3c%2fp%3e%22&r=hello](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%23member%5C%23%29.*%28%3F%3D%5C%23memberstop%5C%23%29&i=%3Cp%3Ehello%20world!%20%23member%23%20Hello%20World%20%23memberstop%23%20test%20data%3C%2Fp%3E%22&r=hello)